# Limits of a composition

Tags: calculus, limits

**NOTE**. We are not allowed to use limits laws. We can only use the **formal definition** of limit. Also im not looking for the answer. I just want to understand how i can relate a limit to composition.
Suppose i have a question like prove $$\text{IF} \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L\;  \text{AND}\; \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = \infty \\
\text{THEN} \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}\; [f(2x) + \frac{g(x)}{2}] = \infty$$
I have an idea of what the proof would be like if its was $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} \;[f(x) + g(x)]$ instead of $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}\; [f(2x) + \frac{g(x)}{2}]$. The outline for the former would be as follows
$$
\text{Fix}\; M > 0.\\
\text{Since} \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L,\; \text{there exists}\; \delta_1 > 0 \; \text{such that}\\
\forall x_1 \in \mathbb{R}, 0 < |x_1 - a| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x_1) - L < 1\\
\text{which is equivalent to}\\
\forall x_1 \in \mathbb{R}, 0 < |x_1 - a| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x_1)| > L - 1\\
\text{Since} \lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = \infty,\; \text{there exists}\; \delta_2 > 0\; \text{such that}\\
\forall x_2 \in \mathbb{R}, 0 < |x_2 - a| < \delta_2 \implies |g(x_2)| > M\\
\text{Take}\; \delta = \text{min}(\delta_1, \delta_2)\\
\text{Let}\; x \in \mathbb{R}. \text{Assume}\; 0 < |x - a| < \delta\\
\text{Since}\; 0 < |x - a| < \delta \leq \delta_1 \;\text{it follows that with}\; x_1 = x \;\text{that}\; f(x) > L - 1.\\
\text{Since}\; 0 < |x - a| < \delta \leq \delta_2 \; \text{it follows that with}\; x_2 = x \;\text{that}\; g(x) > M.\\
\text{Thus we have}
\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\; [f(x) + g(x)] = (L - 1) + M > M
$$

Now the problem im facing is with the fact that there is a $f(2x)$. I know that the $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} 2x = 2a$. How can i use this fact to connect it to $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$. And what about the term $\frac{g(x)}{2}$, how would i connect it to the given $g(x)$?     I appretiate your time and effort.

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)=\infty,$ then $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{g(x)}{2}=\infty.$

Comment: @SahibaArora would that be all the justification necessary?

Comment: No, that just answers your question about how to handle $\frac{g(x)}{2}.$

Comment: Considering that $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to a,$ given any $\varepsilon > 0,$ it follows that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ for all $|x - a| < \delta.$ We want to say that $|f(2x) - L| < \varepsilon$ when $|2x - a|$ is sufficiently small. Can you modify $\delta$ to ensure that this happens? We could say something similar for $\frac{g(x)}{2}.$

Comment: @Carlo how about we say that $|2x - a| < \frac{\delta}{2}$. Would that work?

Comment: @Carlo Because if $ |x - a| < \delta$ then $|2x - a| = 2|x - a/2| < \delta = |x - a/2| < \frac{\delta}{2}$

Comment: Upon further inspection, it might not be true that $\lim_{x \to a} f(2x)$ is finite. Consider the case of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 - x}$ and $a = \frac{1}{2}.$ We have that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1/2} \frac{1}{1 - x} = 2;$ but on the other hand, the limit of $f(2x) = \frac{1}{1 - 2x}$ as $x \to \frac{1}{2}$ does not exist (from the left, it is $+ \infty,$ and on the right, it is $-\infty$).

Comment: But if $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \infty,$ then it is easy to see that $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{2} = \infty.$ Indeed, given any $M \gg 0,$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $g(x) > 2M$ for all $|x - a| < \delta.$ But this implies that $\frac{g(x)}{2} >M$ for all $|x - a| < \delta.$

Comment: @Carlo the a in my question is 0. i didnt write it explicitly because i wanted to know the rule in general. But if my a = 0 (and i also know what L is), then my argument would work right?

Comment: @UnKnoWnZ If $a=0,$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}f(2x)=L.$ (since $x\to 0 \implies 2x \to 0$). Also $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x)}{2}=\infty.$ Then your asseriton is obvious.

Comment: If $a = 0,$ then take $\delta_0 = 2 \delta.$ Consequently, given any $\varepsilon > 0,$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ whenever $|x| = |x - a| < \delta.$ But then, clearly, we have that $|f(2x) - L| < \varepsilon$ whenever $|2x| = 2|x| < 2 \delta = \delta_0,$ and the desired limit is established.